# US to UK spouse visa financial requirement

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, visa, eu-spouses

Since April 2016, I have had an FTC contract that is good until November 2016,  earning 17880 per annum. I also have a permanent, part time role which pays me a 100 a month; this also started in April. I have had a word with my part time employer and he has offered me a full time role after my fixed term contract; the amount per annum is above 18600. Could I use this contract now as spouse visa, as it will be a permanent role, or do I have to wait another 6 months even though I've already been working there part time? I also currently hold 6 months payslips from the FTC and part time roles which exceed 18600.

Thank you in advance for your help.